# Changing the Style of a specific element by Checkbox:Checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styling

I am using a checkbox as a way to modify the other element's style. Is it possible for a checkbox to affect other classes/elements of the website.

I have a sample html code below, instead of changing label element, is it possible to change the styling of the first div instead.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li label {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modify-box">
  BOX TO CHANGED
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <label for="vehicle1"> Bike</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <label for="vehicle2"> Car</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    <label for="vehicle3"> Boat</label><br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want first parent div then css hasn't parent selector

Comment: you need to use Javascript also

Comment: No, that is not possible. Current CSS allows only to select downwards and to the right in the DOM structure, not upwards or to the left. See also: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1427878)

Comment: But if you can modify the HTML structure, then you could put the actual checkbox inputs _before_ the div element -  they are visually hidden anyway, the labels can stay where they are. _Then_ you could select the div element based on the checkbox's status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make this happen, but it's to use exactly the same "trick" with which you style the `<label>` elements, specifically by moving the `<input>` elements ahead of the element you wish to style.

With that in mind, if the `<input>` elements are preceding siblings of the `<div>`, then checking, and unchecking, the `<input>` can have an effect on the `<div>`, and also the original `<label>` elements as well.

As a crude example:

```css
input[type="checkbox"][name^="vehicle"] {
  display: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* styles the <div> based on the checked/unchecked state
   of the <input> (this example assumes that the same
   highlight colour should be used regardless of which
   <input> is checked: */
input[type="checkbox"][name^="vehicle"]:checked ~ div {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* this is where it becomes obvious that JavaScript (or,
   ideally, a CSS selector that can refer to an attribute-
   variable) makes more sense; though with a CSS
   pre-processor this can be written effectively enough.
   Here when the #vehicle1 element is checked the <label>
   descendents with a "for" attribute equal to "vehicle1" of
   later-sibling <ul> elements are selected and styled: */
#vehicle1:checked~ul label[for=vehicle1] {
  background-color: gray;
}

/* as above, for the "vehicle2" id and for attributes: */
#vehicle2:checked~ul label[for=vehicle2] {
  background-color: gray;
}

#vehicle3:checked~ul label[for=vehicle3] {
  background-color: gray;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li label {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<div class="modify-box">
  BOX TO CHANGED
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="vehicle1"> Bike</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="vehicle2"> Car</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="vehicle3"> Boat</label><br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With only CSS this won't be possible. You are restricted by the current selectors and there are no parent selectors in CSS. You can use a bit of JS to target the element you want.

What would you like to happen in the box surrounding the checkboxes? Maybe there would be another solution with a `:before` or `:after` on the label?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need JavaScript for that. You could listen for the `change` event and style if no checkbox is checked.

---

First you need to select the containing list element and attach an event listener to it:

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('change', function(e) {...});
```

In the handler function of the listener you have to check if there is a checked checkbox and depending on that check style your `.modify.box` (or toggle a class, for example `.checked`):

```js
if (document.querySelector('input:checked')) {
  modify_box.classList.add('checked');
}
else {
  modify_box.classList.remove('checked');
}
```

If you decide to toggle a class you need to add that class to your CSS-definition. For example:

```css
ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label,
.checked {...}
```

**Working example:**

```js
const modify_box = document.querySelector('.modify-box');

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (document.querySelector('input:checked')) {
    modify_box.classList.add('checked');
  }
  else {
    modify_box.classList.remove('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label,
.checked {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li label {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modify-box">
  BOX TO CHANGED
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <label for="vehicle1"> Bike</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <label for="vehicle2"> Car</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    <label for="vehicle3"> Boat</label><br>
  </li>
</ul>
```